# Problems Loading data from CSV into a PostgreSQL table with PGADMIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am at a loss. I am on a mac using PG Admin 4 with PostgreSQL I tried to use the import/export data wizard when you right click on the table I created...and get this error ERROR: extra data after last expected column...all of the columns match up and there is no additional data. I don't know what needs to change...

So then I tried to create it with the query tool with the following code (renaming things to put here):

```
create schema schema_name;

create table schema_name.tablename( column1 text, column2 text...); 
 
copy schema_name.tablename
from '/Users/me/downloads/filename.csv'
delimiter ',' header csv;
```

All the columns are of a text datatype.

I get this error message:

> ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/me/downloads/filename.csv" for reading: Permission denied
>
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
> SQL state: 42501

Going to properties for that database, and then to security, and privileges I made public all privileges. But that did nothing. And so I am here to ask all of you for help.

Successfully import the data from the CSV.

Comment: have you chekc the rights in that folder, usually only user have rights there and not the postgres server, copy the file to a temp folder where all have read rights at least

Comment: 1) First issue is probably caused by choice of delimiter and choice of  quoting. Best guess is data has field that contains delimiter character and is not quoted so it is being split into extra field.  Also what  `Format` did you choose csv, text or binary? 2) Second issue, do as error says and use `\copy` in `psql`. This works from the client end and only needs the client's privileges on the file system.